# Check authentication in React Router Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-router-dom, antd

I'm building a React application and the Header component has a Menu button that toggles the sidebar and makes a logout. In other words, it only needs to appear if the user is logged in.

I'm generating a JWT in the backend and storing it in localStorage so an auth() method can get it and decide if user is logged in. The problem is, when I login, the Header doesn't appear. If I refresh the page, it appears. And if I do the opposite, which means logging out, I get redirected to login page but the Header is still there. If I refresh the page, it stops showing itself.

I set a console.log() in the auth method and I realized it doesn't react to trigger properly.

I'm using Ant Design and the app structure is

```
App.tsx
   |
   | - views
   |     |
   |     | -ListProducts accessed by "/" route and only available when logged in
   |     | -Login accessed by "/login" route
   |
   | - components
   |     |
   |     | - Routes.tsx
   |
   | - routines
   |     |
   |     | - auth.ts
```

**App.tsx**

```
import React, { FunctionComponent, useEffect } from "react";
import './assets/styles.css';
import Routes from "./components/Routes";
import { BrowserRouter, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Drawer, List, PageHeader, Button } from "antd";
import { MenuOutlined, PoweroffOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import auth from "./routines/auth";

const App: FunctionComponent = () => {

const [isDrawerVisible, setIsDrawerVisible] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
const routes: {id: number, name: string, route: string}[] = [
    {id: 1, name: "Home", route: "/"},
    {id: 2, name: "Add User", route: "/add-user"}
]

return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        {!auth() && <PageHeader
            className = "site-page-header"
            title = {
                <Button
                    type = "text"
                    shape = "circle"
                    icon = {<MenuOutlined />}
                    size = "large"
                    onClick = {() => setIsDrawerVisible(true)}
                />}
            extra = {[
                <Link key = "1" to = "/logout"><Button danger icon = {<PoweroffOutlined />}>Logout</Button></Link>
            ]}
        />}
        <Drawer
            title = "Hello, 'User'!"
            placement = "left"
            closable
            onClose = {() => setIsDrawerVisible(false)}
            visible = {isDrawerVisible}
            key = "left"
        >
            <List
                itemLayout="horizontal"
                dataSource={routes}
                renderItem={item => (
                  <List.Item>
                    <List.Item.Meta
                      title={<Link to = {item.route} onClick = {() => setIsDrawerVisible(false)} style = {{display: "block"}}>{item.name}</Link>}
                    />
                  </List.Item>
                )}
            />
        </Drawer>

        <Routes />
    </BrowserRouter>
)
}

export default App;
```

**Routes.tsx**

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from "react";
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import ListProducts from "../views/ListProducts";
import Login from "../views/Login";
import AddUser from "../views/AddUser";
import auth from "../routines/auth";
import Logout from "../views/Logout";
import AddProduct from "../views/AddProduct";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest}: any) => (
<Route
    {...rest}
    render = {props => !auth() ? (
        <Component {...props} />
    ) : (
        <Redirect to = {{pathname: "/login", state: {from: props.location}}} />
    )}
/>
)

const Routes: FunctionComponent = () => {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route path = "/login" component = {Login} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path = "/" component = {ListProducts} />
            <PrivateRoute path = "/add-product" component = {AddProduct} />
            <PrivateRoute path = "/add-user" component = {AddUser} />
            <Route path = "/logout" component = {Logout} />
        </Switch>
        )
    }
export default Routes;
```

**auth**

```
const auth = () => {
    const conditionals: boolean[] = [
        localStorage.getItem("token") !== undefined,
        localStorage.getItem("token") !== "",
        localStorage.getItem("token") !== null
    ]
    console.log(conditionals.includes(false); // This command isn't trigger when logging in and logging out
    return conditionals.includes(false);
}
```

export default auth;

Answer (score 1):

When you change the route, say from `ListProducts` to `logout` screen, your `<App />` component doesn't get re-rendered. Only the child components, i.e. `ListProducts` and `Logout` are affected by this action.

Since App component doesn't get re-rendered on route change, your logic for showing/hiding the header component in `App` component is executed only once (i.e. on first launch) and it retains that state the entire session.

You can refer here on how to handle your header menu component - [React: Hide a Component on a specific Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50777333/react-hide-a-component-on-a-specific-route)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, Arpitha and thanks for answering. I checked the link you passed and got the idea, however there is one problem: the PageHeader needs its parent props to open/close the sidenav. If I use withRouter and pass router as props, then in this case I apparently can't have the parent props to control the sidenav.