# React hide menu and footer in a specific page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I will make an employee panel, I do not want to see nav and footer at employee panel. How can I hide those components in a specific page?

Here is my app.js file

```
<Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Menu />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/candidates" component={Candidates} />
            <Route path="/employers" component={Employers} />
            <Route path="/jobadverts" component={JobAdverts} />
            <Route path="/jobadvert/detail/:id" component={JobAdvertDetails} />
            <Route path="/cv/:id" component={Cv} />
            <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
            <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
            <Route path="/postjobadvert" component={JobAdvertPost} />
            <Route path="/panel/employee" component={EmployeePanel} />
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </div>
    </Router>
```

Comment: Duplicate , answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61530545/2931410

Comment: What is the path to admin panel? is it `/panel/employee` ?

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate @KarthikR

Comment: @Erfan Yes, it is panel/employee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `useLocation`, you have access to current rendering path anywhere in your app:

```
const location=useLocation()
```

Now check if is in `panel/employee`

```
const isEmployeePanelRendering = location.pathname==="/panel/employee"
```

Finally, conditionally rendering Footer and Nav based on path:

put this in the first line of the file.

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Switch,useLocation,Route} from "react-router-dom";
```

Put `useLocation` and `isEmployeePanelRendering` in the beginning of `App`

```
 const App=()=>{
    
            const location=useLocation()
            const isEmployeePanelRendering = location.pathname==="/panel/employee"
```

Finally the return part:

```
return   <Router>
        <div className="App">
          {!isEmployeePanelRendering && <Menu />}
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/candidates" component={Candidates} />
            <Route path="/employers" component={Employers} />
            <Route path="/jobadverts" component={JobAdverts} />
            <Route path="/jobadvert/detail/:id" component={JobAdvertDetails} />
            <Route path="/cv/:id" component={Cv} />
            <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
            <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
            <Route path="/postjobadvert" component={JobAdvertPost} />
            <Route path="/panel/employee" component={EmployeePanel} />
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
          </Switch>
          {!isEmployeePanelRendering && <Footer />}
        </div>
    </Router>
```

Comment: I received an error as ""App.js: Unexpected token (28:4)

  26 |   return (
  27 |
> 28 |     const location= useLocation()
     |     ^
  29 |     const isEmployeePanelRendering = location.pathname==="/panel/employee"
  30 |
  31 |     <Router>""

Comment: I wrote const location and isEmployeePanelRendering in function App() and I got that error when I wrote those codes out function App() I get error as ""src\App.js
  Line 24:17:  'useLocation' is not defined
                                         no-undef
  Line 24:17:  React Hook "useLocation" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks""

Comment: @sdkmen i edited my answer

Comment: It worked, thanks for your answers, I am so grateful.

Comment: And I would like to ask one more question if you don't mind. What if I also use this way to second page, how should I use if else block according to syntax?

Comment: Or is there any way to use like if it contains path, I mean lets say the default path is /panel  and I don't want to see menu and footer both of panel/employee panel/employer. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: the condition would be : `const isEmployeePanelRendering = location.pathname.startsWith("/panel/")
`  @sdkmen

Comment: But in such cases, it would be better to not repeat "/panel" route everytime, instead do nested routing : https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting

Comment: Thank you for every answers.

Comment: so far I can't get this working, possibly due to - ```"In V6, you can't use the component prop anymore. It was replaced in favor of element"``` when I try to do it with element I get ```"useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component."```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a RouteWrapper and supply it with a layout of your choice (ie: AdminLayout, EmployeeLayout, etc.)

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { One, Two, Three, Four } from './Components';
import { LayoutOne, LayoutTwo } from './Layouts';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <h3>Content of main App component</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/one">One</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/two">Two</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/three">Three</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/four">Four</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <Switch>
        <RouteWrapper path="/one" component={One} layout={LayoutOne} />
        <RouteWrapper path="/two" component={Two} layout={LayoutOne} />
        <RouteWrapper path="/three" component={Three} layout={LayoutTwo} />
        <RouteWrapper path="/four" component={Four} layout={LayoutTwo} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

function RouteWrapper({
  component: Component, 
  layout: Layout, 
  ...rest
}) {
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) =>
      <Layout {...props}>
        <Component {...props} />
      </Layout>
    } />
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Inspired from https://javascript.plainenglish.io/simple-guide-for-layouts-in-react-router-e32b26c12cee

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried but I do not think I really get it. I could not make it work.